# WCF DataService Expand node with specified condition

Tags: wcf, wcf-data-services, wcf-client

I'm trying to do a simple query:

Method 1:

```
var ss = from h in je.RolesUsers.Expand("Role").Where(h => h.UserID == 1) select h;
```

Method 2:

```
var e = je.RolesUsers.Expand("Role").Where(s => s.UserID == 1);
```

I never get "Role" to be expanded in the result, it is always null. 
Both lines execute the same request to the service:

`http://localhost:5521/JoybaDataService.svc/RolesUsers()?$filter=cast(UserID,'Edm.Int32') eq 1&$expand=Role`

Using this query I get "Role" to be expanded.
any Idea???

Comment: Does your application query for the same entity multiple times? It might be a problem with MergeOption, by default the client will not overwrite any values it already has with the data comming from the server (to avoid data loss). Try to modify the DataServiceContext.MergeOption and see if that helps.